# How to deserialize an empty string to a null value for all `Nullable<T>` value types using System.Text.Json?

Tags: c#, .net-core, system.text.json

In .Net Core 3.1 and using `System.Text.Json` library, I'm facing an issue that didn't occur in Newtonsoft library.

If I send an empty string in JSON for some properties of type (type in backend) `DateTime?` or `int?`, it returns 400 status code with an error message that value can't be deserialized.  However, with Newtonsoft an empty string is automatically interpreted as a null value for any `Nullable<T>.`

A minimal example would be:

```cs
var json = "\"\"";

Assert.AreEqual(null, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTime?>(json)); // Passes
Assert.AreEqual(null, System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<DateTime?>(json));   // Throws System.Text.Json.JsonException: The JSON value could not be converted to System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime].
```

Is there any way to make `System.Text.Json` behave in the same way?  Demo [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gcf02e).

Comment: For now if I'm facing the issue with the `DateTime` type, but I read someone faced the same issue for `Int` type, and maybe for other types, but I don't want to wait till I face the same issues for all types and create custom converter for each one.

Comment: Yes I'm using Nullable types, I just clarified that in the question

Comment: Not sure why this was closed, it's perfectly clear and contains a [mcve].

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the [factory converter pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0#steps-to-follow-the-factory-pattern) to create a [`JsonConverterFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverterfactory?view=net-5.0) that causes an empty string to be interpreted as `null` for all `Nullable<T>` type values.

The following factory does the job:

```
public class NullableConverterFactory : JsonConverterFactory
{
    static readonly byte [] Empty = Array.Empty<byte>();

    public override bool CanConvert(Type typeToConvert) => Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeToConvert) != null;

    public override JsonConverter CreateConverter(Type type, JsonSerializerOptions options) => 
        (JsonConverter)Activator.CreateInstance(
            typeof(NullableConverter<>).MakeGenericType(
                new Type[] { Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(type) }),
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public,
            binder: null,
            args: new object[] { options },
            culture: null);

    class NullableConverter<T> : JsonConverter<T?> where T : struct
    {
        // DO NOT CACHE the return of (JsonConverter<T>)options.GetConverter(typeof(T)) as DoubleConverter.Read() and DoubleConverter.Write()
        // DO NOT WORK for nondefault values of JsonSerializerOptions.NumberHandling which was introduced in .NET 5
        public NullableConverter(JsonSerializerOptions options) {} 

        public override T? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.String)
            {
                if (reader.ValueTextEquals(Empty))
                    return null;
            }
            return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(ref reader, options);
        }           

        public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T? value, JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
            JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, value.Value, options);
    }
}
```

The factory should be added to the [`JsonSerializerOptions.Converters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.converters?view=net-5.0#System_Text_Json_JsonSerializerOptions_Converters) collection of your framework.

Notes:

- In my [original version of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/65025191/1) I cached the return of `(JsonConverter<T>)options.GetConverter(typeof(T))` for performance as recommended by Microsoft.  Unfortunately as noted in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65022834/how-to-deserialize-an-empty-string-to-a-null-value-for-all-nullablet-value-t/65025191#comment119294085_65025191) by [zigzag](https://stackoverflow.com/users/500861/zigzag) Microsoft's own [`DoubleConverter.Read()` and `DoubleConverter.Write()` methods](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/49f4fb85df7339eddd07ce4b6065d370cd93d085/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/Converters/Value/DoubleConverter.cs#L13) do not account for non-default values of [`JsonSerializerOptions.NumberHandling`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/serialization/5.0/jsonserializer-allows-reading-numbers-as-strings), so I have removed this logic as of .NET 5.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MXnhJx).

Comment: `valueConverter.Read(...);` doesn't handle number inside a string. Unfortunately, `ReadNumberWithCustomHandling` method that does handle number inside a string is internal. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: @zigzag - are you setting [`JsonSerializerOptions.NumberHandling = JsonNumberHandling.AllowReadingFromString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/serialization/5.0/jsonserializer-allows-reading-numbers-as-strings) which was introduced in .NET 5?

Comment: Yes, but `valueConverter.Read(...)` call skips that logic. See [source](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/49f4fb85df7339eddd07ce4b6065d370cd93d085/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/Converters/Value/DoubleConverter.cs#L13).

Comment: Well that's unfortunate.  Caching the `valueConverter` is recommended by Microsoft purely for performance reasons, so if it the wrong converter is returned then it would be best to just eliminate it completely.  Remove the `valueConverter` property from `NullableConverter<T>` and just call `Serialize` and `Deserialize` from `Read()` and `Write()` and I think you should be all set.

Comment: I hate System.Text.Json with all of my worldly being. Unless you're running on thousands of servers and NEED the performance boost, do yourself a favor and use the sane, developer friendly Newtsonsoft.Json

Comment: There' s already a `ReadOnlySpan<byte>.Empty` so you don't need your "Empty" variable. Otherwise good answer, helped me write my own converter for `int?`, upvoted