# Automatic conversion of numbers to bools - migrating from Newtonsoft to System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, system.text.json

I accidentally introduced a breaking change in my API by switching to `System.Text.Json` in my ASP.NET Core app. I had a client that was sending a JSON document and was using numbers `1` or `0` for boolean fields instead of `true` or `false`:

```json
// What they're sending.
{ "Active": 1 }

// What they should be sending.
{ "Active": true }
```

The `Newtonsoft.Json` library automatically handled this by casting numbers to bools (0 = `false`, everything else = `true`), but `System.Text.Json` doesn't do this; it throws an exception instead. This means my API endpoints suddenly stopped working for my silly client who's sending `1`'s and `0`'s!

I can't seem to find any mention of this in the migration guide. I would like to restore the behavior back to how Newtonsoft handles it, but I'm not sure if there's a flag to enable it somewhere I'm not seeing, or whether I'll have to write a custom converter.

Could someone help me restore the behavior to be like Newtonsoft's?

---

Here's some code to demonstrate the issue:

```cs
using System;

string data = "{ \"Active\": 1 }";

try
{
    OutputState s1 = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<OutputState>(data);
    Console.WriteLine($"OutputState 1: {s1.Active}");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"System.Text.Json failed: {ex.Message}");
}

try
{
    OutputState s2 = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OutputState>(data);
    Console.WriteLine($"OutputState 2: {s2.Active}");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Newtonsoft.Json failed: {ex.Message}");
}

public record OutputState(bool Active);
```

Also a .NET fiddle for an interactive playground: https://dotnetfiddle.net/xgm2u7

Comment: In your example, it seems that using a record is not allowed by `System.Text.Json`: `System.Text.Json failed: Deserialization of reference types without parameterless constructor is not supported. Type 'OutputState'` (though it works with a class).

Comment: Custom converters can be implemented. Have you tried this approach? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0

Comment: @Métoule It's possible in .NET 5. You are probably on 3.1 or lower: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-immutability?pivots=dotnet-5-0#immutable-types-and-records

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can create a custom [`JsonConverter<bool>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverter-1?view=net-5.0) that emulates the logic of Json.NET's [`JsonReader.ReadAsBoolean()`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/52e257ee57899296d81a868b32300f0b3cfeacbe/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonReader.cs#L684):

```
public class BoolConverter : JsonConverter<bool>
{
    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, bool value, JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
        writer.WriteBooleanValue(value);
    
    public override bool Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
        reader.TokenType switch
        {
            JsonTokenType.True => true,
            JsonTokenType.False => false,
            JsonTokenType.String => bool.TryParse(reader.GetString(), out var b) ? b : throw new JsonException(),
            JsonTokenType.Number => reader.TryGetInt64(out long l) ? Convert.ToBoolean(l) : reader.TryGetDouble(out double d) ? Convert.ToBoolean(d) : false,
            _ => throw new JsonException(),
        };
}
```

Use by adding it to [`JsonSerializerOptions.Converters`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializeroptions.converters?view=net-5.0):

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    Converters = { new BoolConverter() },
};
var s1 = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<OutputState>(data, options);
```

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/szwJ3y).

Notes:

- Json.NET automatically tries to deserialize strings to `bool` using [`bool.TryParse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.boolean.tryparse?view=net-5.0) which parses using a comparison that is *ordinal and case-insensitive.*  Simply checking e.g. [`Utf8JsonReader.ValueTextEquals("true")`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.utf8jsonreader.valuetextequals?view=net-5.0#System_Text_Json_Utf8JsonReader_ValueTextEquals_System_String_) will not emulate Newtonsoft's case invariance.
- Json.NET supports deserializing both integers and floating point numbers to `bool` by attempting to parse the value token to a `long` or `double` (or `decimal` when [`FloatParseHandling.Decimal`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_FloatParseHandling.htm) is set) and then calling [`Convert.ToBoolean()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toboolean?view=net-5.0) on the result.  The converter emulates this logic.
- There may be some boundary conditions where my `BoolConverter<bool>` and Json.NET do not behave identically, particularly for overflow or rounding-near-zero situations.
- If you also need to support deserializing numbers to `bool?`, grab `NullableConverterFactory` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65025191/3744182) to *[How to deserialize an empty string to a null value for all `Nullable<T>` value types using System.Text.Json?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65022834/3744182)* and add it to converters like so:

  ```
   var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
   {
       Converters = { new BoolConverter(), new NullableConverterFactory() },
   };
  ```

  This converter factory also fixes another obscure breaking change from Newtonsoft to System.Text.Json, namely that the former will deserialize an empty JSON string `""` to any `Nullable<T>` but the latter will not.

  Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8FIdWb).

Comment: Alternatively, you can specify a converter to deserialize specific property using an attribute: `[JsonConverter(typeof(BoolConverter))]bool Active { get;set; }`. Then you'd just call `Deserialize` as usual.