Razor Pages unable to convert 'True' to Boolean
I'm doing an AJAX call from Razor Pages. On the backend, I have something like this.
public class ArriveRailcarInfo
{
    public string Railcar { get; set; }
    public string Product { get; set; }
    public string Customer { get; set; }
    public bool IsLoaded { get; set; }
}

// Verifies the list of products are in the system
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostValidateRailcarsAsync([FromBody] IEnumerable<ArriveRailcarInfo> railcars)
{
    // Validate railcars...
}

The JavaScript to create the data passed to the AJAX call looks something like this.
var railcars = [];
$checkedItems.each(function () {
    var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
    railcars.push({
        Railcar: $row.data('railcar'),
        Product: $row.data('product'),
        Customer: $row.data('customer'),
    });
});

This works fine. But if I add the IsLoaded member, then railcars is null on the backend.
var railcars = [];
$checkedItems.each(function () {
    var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
    railcars.push({
        Railcar: $row.data('railcar'),
        Product: $row.data('product'),
        Customer: $row.data('customer'),
        IsLoaded: $row.data('isloaded'),
    });
});

This also fails.
var railcars = [];
$checkedItems.each(function () {
    var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
    railcars.push({
        Railcar: $row.data('railcar'),
        Product: $row.data('product'),
        Customer: $row.data('customer'),
        IsLoaded: 'true',
    });
});

However, this works.
var railcars = [];
$checkedItems.each(function () {
    var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
    railcars.push({
        Railcar: $row.data('railcar'),
        Product: $row.data('product'),
        Customer: $row.data('customer'),
        IsLoaded: true,
    });
});

So, I could convert the value to lower case, generate a true Boolean value, and use that. But can anyone tell me why the first version doesn't work? Why can't Razor Pages convert 'True' to a true value?
Payload
Here are the payloads being sent.
Fails
[{"Railcar":"WFRX409179","Product":"SAND FRACING 100 MESH","Customer":"FML TERMINAL LOGISTICS LLC","IsLoaded":"True"},{"Railcar":"TILX339447","Product":"SAND FRACING 100 MESH","Customer":"FML TERMINAL LOGISTICS LLC","IsLoaded":"True"},{"Railcar":"MRMX016512","Product":"SAND FRACING 100 MESH","Customer":"FML TERMINAL LOGISTICS LLC","IsLoaded":"True"}]

Succeeds
[{"Railcar":"SOXX003565","Product":"SAND FRACING 100 MESH","Customer":"FML TERMINAL LOGISTICS LLC","IsLoaded":true},{"Railcar":"WFRX410561","Product":"SAND FRACING 100 MESH","Customer":"FML TERMINAL LOGISTICS LLC","IsLoaded":true},{"Railcar":"GBRX069166","Product":"SAND FRACING 100 MESH","Customer":"FML TERMINAL LOGISTICS LLC","IsLoaded":true},{"Railcar":"TILX337762","Product":"SAND FRACING 100 MESH","Customer":"FML TERMINAL LOGISTICS LLC","IsLoaded":true}]


Try watching the RAW form data in the request on the server. How do they differ?

why would you expect 'True' string to be mapped to true boolean?

@YehorAndrosov: Because that's what .NET does. It converts text into the corresponding values. Also, I'm not sure why it is a string anyway. I'm getting it from a data value. I never specified that it should be a string. How can I tell it the value is not a string?

Afaik, only numbers may be binded from string to value, but it depends on a culture selected. A variety of what can be true/false is way wider - "Yes/No", their alternatives in other languages etc. So I wouldn't expect such conversion by default. data() returns a string because this is how html attributes work, they store everything as a text

What you could do is data() == 'true' to convert string value to boolean

@YehorAndrosov: Yeah, it becomes $row.data('isloaded').toLowerCase() == 'true'. But I don't really get why that is necessary.

Just because there is no code in asp.net that does this conversion for you. Usually, this is solved by writing custom model binders

Just curious: Can you actually use a number as a string and have it deserialize to a number?

check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75089641/2385435

Actually full solution because it took me some time to figure out you need to decorate the property:
public class StringToBoolJsonConverter : JsonConverter<bool>
{
    public override bool Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.True)
            return true;

        if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.False)
            return false;

        var s = reader.GetString() ?? "";

        if (s.Equals("true", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            return true;

        if (s.Equals("false", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            return false;

        throw new JsonException("Boolean property must be \"true\" or \"false\".");
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, bool value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        => writer.WriteBooleanValue(value);
}

And crucially:
public class ArriveRailcarInfo
{
    public string Railcar { get; set; }
    public string Product { get; set; }
    public string Customer { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(StringToBoolJsonConverter))]
    public bool IsLoaded { get; set; }
}

This will work with the JSON props being bools or strings.
I thought you could register the converter globally in program.cs, but I couldn’t get it to work?
