# Read in Byte value and convert to Null

Tags: c#, system.text.json

I am trying to write a function that handles empty values for the datatype `Byte`.

The reader is reading in a JSON string and serializing to my models.

One of the models has a `Byte` property.

If the reader encounters a blank or empty string for a Byte, then it should convert it to Null.

But whenever the function is used, I get this error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot get the value of a token type 'String' as a number.'
```

Here is my function:

```
    public override Byte? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var @byte = reader.GetByte();
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(@byte.ToString()))
        {
            return null;
        }
        return Byte.Parse(@byte.ToString());
    }
```

I am not sure why it is giving me the error or how to fix?

Thanks!

Comment: `return Byte.Parse(@byte.ToString());` <-- so return `return @byte;` with more steps?

Comment: Also `@byte.ToString()` could never ever be `null` or whitespace. It sounds like your JSON has a `string` value, not a `byte` value. Perhaps you meant to use `reader.GetString()`?

Comment: Worse, @byte *might* be null, so the `ToString` will NPE while you're checking for null.

Comment: @Gus `@byte` can't ever be `null`. At worse it would be `(byte)0`, but then `((byte)0).ToString()` would yield `"0"`, which isn't `null` or empty.

Comment: Interesting; so I suppose if it's asked to `getByte()` on no data, it should throw an exception at that time.  There's no try/catch here for that case either

Comment: Your method has a typeToConvert parameter you might want to check it. Your reader is currently somewhere in your json so i assume you are guessing on your side that its a byte currently. Or is your json completely consisting only of byte types?

Comment: Seems like a special case of [How to deserialize an empty string to a null value for all `Nullable<T>` value types using System.Text.Json?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65022834/3744182).

Comment: In fact, it might be a duplicate of [How to deserialize an empty string to a null value for all `Nullable<T>` value types using System.Text.Json?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65022834/3744182), agree?

Comment: @Ralf it's an extension method for my models and is used in the `getter` section for byte properties in my models

Comment: @dbc so I can treat the byte as a string?  I will check out that question link you posted, thanks!

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar I did try `reader.GetString()` and got the same error :(

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell - The linked question asks how to map an empty string to a null nullable for all `Nullable<T>` types.  You want to do it specifically for `Nullable<Byte>`, so your question seems like a specific case of that one.  That being said, since you know you are deserializing a `Byte` you can replace `return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(ref reader, options)` with `return reader.GetByte()`.  The important thing is the `if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.String && reader.ValueTextEquals(Empty)) return null;` check before that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your issue is that you have a string value in from JSON and you're trying to read that as a `Byte`. Instead, you should try reading it as a string first:

```
public override Byte? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
{
    string raw = reader.GetString();
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(raw)) {
        return null;
    }

    return Byte.Parse(raw);
}
```

This will do what you want: parse the data as a Byte if it's available or return null if it's empty or missing. As an aside, you should really make use of type-checking to ensure a broader use-case rather than relying on a string-input.

Comment: Maybe it's better to use TryParse or wrap in a try catch in order not make to program to terminate in case of the string is not contaning a valid byte numebr

Comment: @MarcoBeninca do you mean use `return Byte.TryParse(raw); ` instead of `return Byte.Parse(raw); ` ? Thanks

Comment: You cannot return directly return Byte.TryParse because it return a boolean... you have to pass a byte and test for the result of TryParse and if false return a default value [ByteTryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.byte.tryparse?view=net-6.0)

Comment: When I try that  on your example I get this, `System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot get the value of a token type 'Number' as a string.` on the line, `string raw = reader.GetString();`

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell Them your JSON isn't a string. I don't know what your JSON looks like so I can't give you anymore than that.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't think is an elegant solution or even a proper one, I got this to work by 1) Checking the `TokenType` and 2) converting it to an int to check for null or empty.

```
    public override Byte? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var tokenType = reader.TokenType;
        if(tokenType == JsonTokenType.Number)
        {
            var @byte = reader.GetByte();
            var intVal = Convert.ToInt32(@byte);
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(intVal.ToString()))
            {
                return null;
            }
            return @byte;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: @dbc is this what you meant?

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar , do you think this solution is acceptable?  Thanks

Comment: You should be able to copy the solution as-is from [How to deserialize an empty string to a null value for all `Nullable<T>` value types using System.Text.Json?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65025191/3744182), is it not working for you?

Comment: @dbc Mine is an extension method for one of my models.  That solution seemed really broad and I'm not sure if it would work in .Net 6 using System.Text.Json...